# SQL Azure server as unit of billing

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

One of the azure training kit presentation says:

> Each account has zero or more logical
>   servers
>
> - Provisioned via a common portal
> - Establishes a billing instrument
>
> Each **logical server** has one or more
>   databases
>
> - Contains metadata about database &    usage
> - **Unit of authentication, geo-location,    billing, reporting**
> - Generated DNS-based name
>
> Each database has standard SQL objects
>
> - Users, Tables, Views, Indices, etc
> - Unit of consistency

So now I'm lost :D. Were not the databases themselves the units of billing?

I mean, I thought that servers were just like logical containers and you were charged per number and size of databases. How servers are billed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your subscription, when you set up SQL Azure, you effectively create a logical server, located in one of six data centers. By default, a subscription supports a single logical server. I'm guessing you'd have to contact Microsoft to increase this quota. In any case, you don't pay at all for the "server" - there's no data space allocated.

You pay strictly per database. Each database tier has a monthly rate, amortized daily based on maximum database size for each day. This will save you money if your database size is dynamic. For instance: Assume you have a Web edition database, which has two tiers: 1GB and 5GB. Let's say that most of the month, your daily usage falls below 1GB, but for a week, you run at about 1.5GB. You'll pay at the 5GB rate for that week, but at the 1GB rate for the rest of the month (this is a significant savings over paying the 5GB rate for the entire month).

If you load up a 5GB database, the price is equivalent to having five 1GB databases, even if those 1GB databases existed in different logical servers.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder how many lawyers & programmers put that description together :/

Technically a database is married to a server and is billed by by gigabyte/month.

Comment: But a server may contain several databases... So, if I create a sever with 2 databases, is the same price as 2 servers witn one database each?